# Getting the raw pointer from a smart pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

Apologies if this is a duplicate.. Hopefully it is not. I searched through a long list of questions, but they all seemed to not really explain it.

Here goes: In the follwoing

```
int main(int,char**){
    auto a = make_unique<std::string>("Hello World");

    // do stuff with either &*a or a.get()

    return 0;
}
```

is there any difference between `&*a` and `a.get()` ? I know they both return the raw pointer value (unless `operator&` is overloaded), but are there any runtime advantages to picking one over the other?

Comment: `&*a` is undefined behavior if the raw pointer is nullptr.

Comment: wouldn't `&*a` simply be 0 if `a` were `nullptr`?

Comment: prefer `get`, that is what it's for, more clearly conveys intent, and is easier to read

Answer (score 6):

`&*a` is undefined behavior if the pointer is nullptr. You can learn more about undefined behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

In all other cases I'd expect both solutions to be quite equivalent. I would prefer to use `get()` because this is the direct way which everyone understands.

From the C++ Standard:

**20.9.1.2.4 unique_ptr observers [unique.ptr.single.observers]**

typename add_lvalue_reference::type operator*() const;
1 Requires: get() != nullptr.
2 Returns: *get().

Comment: +1 for the standards reference :) I tried compiling once with each.. `g++ -o test test.cpp`.. the binaries differ, so not quite the same, I guess. Not sure how to tell which is faster though..

Comment: @born2smile use the optimizer (-O) and compare

Comment: ah, indeed. With the optimizer the two compile to the same code. I wonder what consequence this has if `a` is `nullptr`

Comment: @Born2Smile : The behavior of undefined behavior is undefined. ;-]